# SimpleXml Element: Special Characters Error

Tags: php, character-encoding, simplexml

I am using simpleXml to parse my xml but it always breaks the page when i try to parse Spanish, french, Estonian, Portuguese, superscripts or subscripts.

Any Idea ??

Example of the XML :-

```
<carddata> <logo_id>0</logo_id> <cscale>Ñ</cscale><carddata>
```

Scripts :-

```
$carddetail = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$carddetail = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT', $carddetail);
```

In the xml i sent

```
<cscale><![CDATA[Peter Nortoné]]></cscale>
```

and the error is:

```
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 22: parser error : CData section not finished Peter Nort in D:\xampp\htdocs\logosnap\card.php on line 144

Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <text><\![CDATA[Peter Norton in D:\xampp\htdocs\logosnap\card.php on line 144
```

Comment: `<carddata>
<logo_id>0</logo_id>
<cscale>Ñ</cscale><carddata>`

Comment: PHP Code: `$carddetail = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);   $carddetail = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT', $carddetail);`

Comment: turn out you have use the iconv wrongly, can you double check what is the charset for the XML string? If is already is UTF-8,why bother to convert to ISO?

Answer (score 1):

```
$carddetail = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);  
<-- this set $carddetail as simplexmlelement object
```

You can't use the object as string like :-

```
$carddetail = iconv('UTF-8', 'ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT', $carddetail);
```

So, try this :-

```
$carddetail = new SimpleXMLElement(iconv('UTF-8','ISO-8859-15//TRANSLIT',$xml));
```

Comment: In the xml i sent  
`<cscale><![CDATA[Peter Nortoné]]></cscale>`  
and the error is  `Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: Entity: line 22: parser error : CData section not finished Peter Nort in D:\xampp\htdocs\logosnap\card.php on line 144  
Warning: SimpleXMLElement::__construct() [simplexmlelement.--construct]: <text><![CDATA[Peter Norton in D:\xampp\htdocs\logosnap\card.php on line 144`